# URL scheme to launch Blackberry Messenger (BBM), like mailto or tel

Tags: blackberry, custom-url, bb-messenger

Is there a custom URL scheme which can launch Blackberry Messenger on Blackberry phones? I'm looking for something like "mailto" or "tel", where clicking it would open BBM and ideally let me pre-fill the text: `<a href="bbm:?text=Hi there">share by BBM</a>` or similar. To be clear, this is not so I can send BBMs on behalf of the user: this is just to open the BBM app, by having the user click a link in a webpage viewed on their Blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

A chat can be started using a URL like BBM.  The PIN should use upper case characters.  If the user isn't a BBM contact a card opens for the user to invite the contact to become a BBM contact.  This doesn't allow you to supply text.

You can supply text if you use the invocation framework on BlackBerry 10.  See this page for details.

[Invoking BBM](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/bbm.html)